# Don't display messages which are replies to blocked users

Tags: feature-request, chat, ignored-users

Today we had some code dumper in the Lounge, and people have been complaining loudly about me banning such people, so I used the block feature instead. But my screen is still full of messages of the other room members replying to that person, so it hardly actually achieves anything.

Can we please change the ignore feature so that when you ignore someone, it really ignores them? The current implementation is like, "You still have to watch the conversation you didn't want to be a part of, but now it doesn't even make sense since one of the participants is missing".

Comment: This should be a separate option, if implemented at all. I *do* want to see if others are interacting with someone I blocked.